# Debugging javascript for webforms project hosted on iis

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, iis, webforms, client-side-scripting

I have a webforms project hoted on iis that i run on internet explorer. For debugging the server code on visual studio i place a 'stop' on the required position or attach to w3 process in visual studio.
However i am unable to do so if i want to debug the client side js code.
I can place a debugger in the js file and in the js file rendered to the browser the debugger is present however it is not hit while the page executes. Ex: i have placed a debugger in the onload() method but does not hit.
Can anyone tell a better, structured way that actually works..

Comment: As WebForms is a mixture of JavaScript and .NET, you need both the JavaScript debugger in IE and a .NET debugger attached to `w3wp.exe` to debug different parts of a web app. When a break point does not hit, check if you are debugging a debug build, not a release build.

Answer (score 0):

The client side debug must work if you have attached #debugger keyword in the javascript. In order to #debugger work, you must press F12 and keep the IE in the developer mode. I guess that's the problem in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether script debugging is enabled in your IE.

- Open Internet Explorer
- Go to Internet Options
- Go to the Advanced Tab
- Set both Disable script debugging to unchecked

[image]